# Azure Table SDK 2 EntityResolver using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to use `EntityResolver` to dynamically populate an empty object from an Azure `TableResult.Execute`, debug doesnt get into the `Test` method unless you omit the `match.SetValue` call. It throws an exception stating the below. The actual azure table request is fine and in debug I can see the column values etc, I just need to map it into a local class, ideally using generics and reflection.

```
Method not found: 'System.Nullable`1<Int32> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty.get_Int32Value()'.
```

I think the problem is something to do with reflection but need assistance.

```
public T RetrieveRow(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        EntityResolver<IObTable> resolver = (pk, rk, ts, props, etag) => Test(props);
        CloudTable table = base.TableClient.GetTableReference(TableName);
        TableOperation operation = TableOperation.Retrieve<IObTable>(partitionKey, rowKey, resolver);
        TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(operation);
        return (T)retrievedResult.Result;
    }

public IObTable Test(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> storageProps)
    {
        IObTable objectToReturn = (IObTable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        if (storageProps != null)
        {
            var emptyObjectProps = objectToReturn.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in storageProps)
            {
                PropertyInfo match = emptyObjectProps.FirstOrDefault(v=> v.Name==prop.Key);
                if (match!=null)
                {
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(prop, storageProps[match.Name].Int32Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return objectToReturn;
    }
```

`IObTable` is just a marker interface on my local entity.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:
match.SetValue(prop, storageProps[match.Name].Int32Value);

to this:
match.SetValue(objectToReturn, storageProps[match.Name].Int32Value);

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather long way to do, but it works:

```
    //TEntity is any class derived from TableEnitity 
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> TestingGetPartitionEntities(string PartitionKey)
    {

        TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> query = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(
              TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, PartitionKey));

            EntityResolver<TEntity> resolver = (pk, rk, ts, props, etag) => 
            {
                //MUST create the 'reflected' instance in the 'EntityResolver', so resolver can create new instance foreach entity in query execution loop.
                TEntity objectToReturn = (TEntity)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TEntity));
                var objectProperties = objectToReturn.GetType().GetProperties();

                foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    PropertyInfo match = objectProperties.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Name == prop.Key);
                    if (match != null)
                    {
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(objectToReturn, props[match.Name].Int32Value);
                    }
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(object))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(objectToReturn, props[match.Name].PropertyAsObject);
                    }
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(objectToReturn, props[match.Name].BooleanValue);
                    }
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(byte[]))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(objectToReturn, props[match.Name].BinaryValue);
                    }
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(objectToReturn, props[match.Name].DateTimeOffsetValue);
                    }
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(double))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(objectToReturn, props[match.Name].DoubleValue);
                    }
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(objectToReturn, props[match.Name].GuidValue);
                    }
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(objectToReturn, props[match.Name].Int32Value);
                    }
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(long))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(objectToReturn, props[match.Name].Int64Value);
                    }
                    if (match.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        match.SetValue(objectToReturn, props[match.Name].StringValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            return objectToReturn as TEntity;
        };

        //This is the list that is returned to caller.
        List<TEntity> results = new List<TEntity>();
        foreach (TEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query, resolver, null, null))
        {
            results.Add(entity as TEntity);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an implementation of the EntityResolver delegate in the Azure Storage assembly itself (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll), called `EntityUtility.ResolveEntityByType<T>`, which you can likely adapt to your needs. That class is internal so you'll have to disassemble the dll, but there are many tools to do that (Reflector is great and ILSpy is free).

Comment: No need to disassemble: the code is [available on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Table/EntityUtilities.cs)